# Unable to flash custom recovery in Samsung j1 ace

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-j1

I am trying to use the TWRP custom recovery on my device but am unable to do so.

First I made sure I had the latest ADB and Samsung drivers. Downloaded the TWRP .tar file which is compatible( I think so, its not the exact model number, which is SM-J110H) with my device. Then I proceeded to run Odin, connect the phone to the PC using an usb cable, and put the phone in download mode.

Everything was working alright until I 'flashed'(Put the TWRP file in AP, clicked Start, the log showed 'All threads completed. (succeed 1 / failed 0)
').
 After that, my phone rebooted. Now, whenever I try to go to recovery mode or boot my phone, it just hangs and a red exclamation mark is shown at the top left. 
I have fixed it by flashing the stock firmware but would like to know why it doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that your recovery image (.tar file) is either uncompatible or corrupted.

To prevent this :

- Double-check that your recovery image is compatible with your exact
  phone model. If it's not, ask the developer about it.
- Check the control sum (md5sum, sha256sum, etc.) of your file once downloaded. If it's different from the sum on the website, download
  it again (from another miror if possible).

You may also use Heimdall instead of Odin to flash your recovery image : https://www.glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/